# Argument error, options.body in node.js?

Tags: node.js, express

what is the problem i don't know please help to solve this. when i post data then below error shows on terminal. Attach is the code also.

```
Error: Argument error, options.body.
    at Request.init (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/index.js:351:13)
    at new Request (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/index.js:124:8)
    at Object.request (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/index.js:1279:11)
    at Request._callback (/var/www/html/nodeproject/helloworld/controllers/login.js:68:11)
    at Request.self.callback (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/index.js:148:22)
    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/index.js:896:14)
    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/index.js:847:12)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
```

below is my code here am posting data using json.

```
module.exports.controller = function(BASE) {
         var token_array = new Array();

         BASE.APP.get('/login', function(req, res)
    {
        res.render('pages/login');
             //res.sendFile(__dirname + '/login.html');

    });



 BASE.APP.post("/login", BASE.urlEncodedParser, function(req, response)
           {

            var devicetoken = req.usersession.devicetoken;
            var body = req.body;
            req.usersession.username = body.username;

                console.log(req.body);
                var userData={
                    "deviceToken" : devicetoken,
                    "password" : body.pwd,
                    "username" : body.username
                };
                var digest = BASE.utils.hmac("sha1", "A12AA418-1F28-4464-8B67-29CBD02BC45C-F048B14F-F3E3-4F97-A522-F2275A364A0E", JSON.stringify(userData));
                var postData = {
                    "deviceToken" : devicetoken,
                    "password"    : body.pwd,
                    "username"    : body.username,
                    "digest"      : digest
                };

                var sPostData = BASE.utils.base64encode(BASE.utils.base64encode(JSON.stringify(postData)));
                BASE.request({
                    url: "http://example.com/authenticate/",
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: {
                        "content-type": "application/json",
                    },
                    body: sPostData
                },
                function(err,result,body){
                    //console.log(JSON.stringify(postData));

                    var body = JSON.parse(body);
                    req.usersession.token = body.token;

                    /*********************************has login permission***************************************/
                    var loginData={


                         "permission" : '08008749-F3A5-480B-A2B2-C21CEFED70F4',
                        "token" : req.usersession.token

                    };



                    var logindigest = BASE.utils.hmac("sha1", "A12AA418-1F28-4464-8B67-29CBD02BC45C-F048B14F-F3E3-4F97-A522-F2275A364A0E", JSON.stringify(loginData));
                    var loginpostData = {

                                 "permission" : '08008749-F3A5-480B-A2B2-C21CEFED70F4',
                                "token" : req.usersession.token,
                                "digest"      :  logindigest

                                  };

                    BASE.request({
                            url : "http://example.com/hasPermission/",
                            method :"POST",
                            headers : {

                                        "content-type": "application/json",
                                      },
                            body :loginpostData
                                },
                    function (err,result1,body) {

                        console.log(body);          

                    });     

                    //response.redirect(301, '/contacts');
                }); 

            }); 

}
```

i am using same type code of another file what it should not give any error but this file show me

Answer (score 88):

Try adding `json: true` in your request options.

For example:

```
BASE.request({
    url : "http://example.com/hasPermission/",
    method :"POST",
    headers : {
        "content-type": "application/json",
    },
    body: loginpostData,
    json: true
},
```